# Docker Error: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): "...msader15.dll.mui: no such file or directory"

Tags: asp.net, docker

I am trying to build my ASP.NET 4.7.2 WEB Services into a docker file, however when I run

```
docker build -t manufacturing-portal-api:latest .
```

I get the following error:

```
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): link /Files/Program Files/common files/system/ado/en-US/msader15.dll.mui /Files/Program Files (x86)/common files/system/ado/en-US/msader15.dll.mui: no such file or directory=> => sha256:d9e8b01179bfc94a5bdb1810fbd76b999aa52016001ace2d3a4c4bc7065a9601 1.66GB / 1.66GB                     0.0s
```

This is my docker file

```html
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk-windowsservercore-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY WebPortalAPI/*.csproj ./WebPortalAPI/
COPY WebPortalAPI/*.config ./WebPortalAPI/
COPY ./instantclient_11_2 .
ENV PATH=./instantclient_11_2
ENV TNS_ADMIN=./instantclient_11_2/network/admin
RUN nuget restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY WebPortalAPI/. ./WebPortalAPI/
WORKDIR /app/WebPortalAPI
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release


FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803 AS runtime
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=build /app/WebPortalAPI/. ./
```

please advise

Comment: Still getting this error even after switching to Windows Containers. Any other solution?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your Docker host is likely configured to run Linux containers inside of a VM. To run Windows containers, you need to "Switch to Windows containers" in the Docker context menu (on the taskbar icon). Documentation on that is [available here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers).

Comment: I'm already in "Windows containers" mode and am still getting this error. Using `FROM --platform=windows/x86-64 python:3.10.4-windowsservercore`.

Comment: @eccentricOrange same here. Still getting the error while having Docker on windows containers. Used FROM --platform=windows/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/windows/server:ltsc2022-amd64, and tried to build the Docker but it failed after downloading everything. Did you manage to solve that ?

Comment: Right-click on the Docker icon in the system tray and select "Switch to Windows containers" from the context menu.