# Docker micaut.dll.mui error while creating docker container for .net standard framework 4.8 lts

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, cicd, .net-4.8

failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): link /Files/Program Files/common files/Microsoft Shared/Ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui /Files/Program Files (x86)/common files/Microsoft Shared/ink/en-US/micaut.dll.mui: no such file or directory

**Docker file:**
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.csproj .

RUN dotnet restore "xyz.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "xyz.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "xyz.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "xyz.dll"]

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66083090

> Your Docker host is likely configured to run Linux containers inside of a VM. To run Windows containers, you need to "Switch to Windows containers" in the Docker menu.

Comment: Right-click on the Docker icon in the system tray and select "Switch to Windows containers" from the context menu.